# Azure resource manager windows VM accessing endpoints from internet not working

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have installed mirthconnect on windows virtual machine in azure resource manager. I am able to access admin console with http://localhost:8080 .But same is not accessible from internet. I have added endpoints in network security.[image: Below is NSG rules for the winodws VM]

Is there any other configuration I am missing here ?
I am able to RDP to the machine . I have tried with source as * and destination as * also . But still no luck.

I am not able to telnet also with the VM public IP and  the given ports.

Comment: Did you allow 8080/TCP from anywhere for all profiles in the Windows Firewall on the VM? Is you daemon binding to 0.0.0.0 or just 127.0.0.1? (`netstat -ban` should give you the answer there).

Comment: @evilSnobu You should add that as an answer. If NSG allows the traffic then it must be the firewall blocking it, or as you said, binding only to localhost or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to your Virtual Machine, Open the Firewall Advanced Settings and add an exception for the port 8080 as the EndPoint Configuration doesn't do that for you

Answer (score 1):

Did you allow **8080/TCP** **from anywhere**, **for all profiles** in Windows Firewall?

Is you daemon listening on **0.0.0.0** or just **127.0.0.1**?

```
netstat -ban
```

should give you the answer there.
e.g.

```
[spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1540           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[lsass.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2179           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[vmms.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

If you're only listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) you need to address the configuration of your daemon and then restart it.